# PCB ground plane oscillation

Tags: pcb, ground

I always wondered if PCB ground plane can do harm when talking about amplifiers. When I say harm I mean oscillations, humming, or buzzing. Because I always thought, that PCB ground plane is like a ground loop and this loop can make an amplifier oscillate. So now, I am not sure if it is ok to use a copper pour as a ground plane or not. If it is better to just use a trace which will be ground, or use a whole pcb ground plane as a ground.

Comment: *Because I heard...* <-- please link to the source of that dodgy/sketchy sounding information.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I thought this, not heard.

Comment: It depends too much, IMO. But generally, ground loops are not an issue, unless in some ill-designed exceptions that **abuse** the ground node as signal return, notably 20th century(-inspired) single-ended audio amps. Don't use single-ended signalling for precision stuff, period. And all the voodoo about ground loops vanishes.

Answer (score 1):

As always, how to arrange the grounding in a circuit depends on the circuit and how the components or blocks are arranged on PCB and how the wiring will end up. Some circuits work better with star grounding, some circuits work better with a ground plane.

In an audio amplifier that amplifies small voltage levels into high output currents, it is always important to arrange your grounding and components so that the large currents flowing in the copper don't cause voltage drops where they will add to sensing the small input signal, regardless of what kind of grounding you use.

So if you make a circuit that happens to be sensitìve how you connect the ground wires, then grounding matters. Otherwise, the grounding does not matter as long as it is good enough for the circuit.

Another thing is to think why something oscillates. For example, a wire has some non-zero self-inductance. Two parallel wires makes a transformer which can couple a signal. A wire has some non-zero capacitance to surrounding wires, so two parallel wires have capacitance between them which can couple a signal.

The problem is, which is worse, having a signal which couples to another signal nearby, or a signal which couples to ground, because incorrect coupling or extra capacitance in the wrong place can cause instability and oscillations.